# Making ng-click work with jqGrid column formatter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqgrid

I'm building an AngularJS application where I'm using jqGrid to display a list of buildings. Each row contains information about that building along with two buttons.

- An edit button that links to a detail screen
- A delete button that will remove the building from the backend database.

I aim to add these buttons to the grid by using the `formatter` callback on the jqGrid config object, which is passed to the jqGrid directive.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the `ng-click` binding to call the function I have assigned to it.

I have created a plunker that demonstrates my issue. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/2UDdNjfwCLauhlw1z3oL?p=preview

How do I get this `ng-click` binding to work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any new element injected in AngularJS element, that needs to be compile by using `$compile` service. After the compilation of angular directives & scope variable binding will work. I'd suggest you to compile the table on `loadComplete` event of `jqgrid`, as this event event called when `jqgrid` fully gets render, & also replace `$.extend` with `angular.extend` that will make code more readable in angular way. Pager element should also gone through compile cycle before appending it DOM.

**Directive** (link function)

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('config', function(newValue) {
        element.children().empty();
        var table = angular.element('<table id="' + newValue.id + '"></table>');
        element.append($compile(table)(scope));
        angular.extend(newValue, {
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'Rows',
                page: 'Page',
                total: 'Total',
                records: 'Records',
                repeatitems: false
            },
            viewrecords: true,
            rowNum: 15,
            loadComplete: function() {
                //compiling DOM after table load
                $compile(angular.element('#' + newValue.id))(scope);
            },
            rowList: [15, 30, 50],
            altRows: true
        });
        if (newValue.pager) {
            var pager = angular.element('<div id="' + newValue.pager + '"></table>');
            element.append($compile(pager)(scope));
            angular.extend(newValue, {
                pager: '#' + newValue.pager,
                pagerpos: "center",
                recordpos: "right",
                pgbuttons: true,
                pginput: true
            });
        }
        angular.element(table).jqGrid(newValue);
    });
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YHJuZrV9FV3RqPDDYKju?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, still required any thing you can ask me anytime, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out in the morning - looks great at first glance!

Comment: @CameronWilby Your welcome, let me know if you have any more doubts on this, Thanks :)